# how to get static URL inside GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

my `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static

  - url: /.*
    script: main.app
```

is there a way, inside my webapp2 code, to get the absolute URL of the `/static` route?

Comment: you mean checking the static files are in that folder? and knowing what absolute url they have?

Comment: I mean in my app I need to emit the absolute URL for my static files. this is because I need to publish the URL externally. I need to post a URL for one of my script files on to an external service (shopify) for them to call this URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define routes in your application you can compute an uri. See: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#building-uris 
With this information and your knowledge of the app.yaml you can compute the uri for the static url.

In your main.app you add a dummy route definition for static. It will only be used to build the uri and it will never be used for routing.

Modified example from the webapp2 docs :

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', handler='HomeHandler', name='home'),
    webapp2.Route('/static', handler=HomeHandler, name='static'), # never used for routing
])
```

Comment: thanks. that was my suspicion that I cannot avoid repeating myself and having the pat hardcoded in the code as well as in the yaml file.

Comment: Could the full solution possibly be posted on this?  Would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no way to query, loop or find out what is in a folder that was uploaded as static.

but the static files do not change as long as you wont deploy the app with new static files.

you need to keep of the static files and compose those absolute urls yourself